# Can pseudo elements inherit color from parent element?

Tags: css

Some Javascript code changes the color of a certain element to which I created a pseudo-element. I want the latter to get whatever color its parent element gets (from JS). `color: inherit` applied to the pseudo element doesn't work though.

Why not and how to achieve this?

Comment: please share enough code so that we can have enough information to help you (html and js)

Comment: Do you mean to set "background-color" and not "color"? color refers to text

Comment: JS code is off topic, HTML code is so basic there's really no point: div { color: red; position relative; } div:after { position: absolute; content: "-"'; left: 0; color: inherit; }. Here you go. This doesn't add any useful info to my question.

Comment: Yes, color. The content of my pseudo-element is text (a dash character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `color: inherit` works just fine.

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
        document.getElementById('d').style.color = 'green';
}, 1000);
```

```css
#d {
    color: red;
}
#d::before {
    color: inherit;
    content: "before";
}
```

```html
<div id="d">text</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand. On my page I see the element changing colors but its pseudo-element doesn't change!